# Generate Base64WebSafe strings by using 'CryptoStreams' and 'ToBase64Transform'

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

Some people in the community advised me to use CryptoStream in order to encode large files with Base64 for better performance, and that's what I did.

The difference in this context, instead of reading the bytes from the files, is that I can't get from the file (read as a stream of bytes in a CryptoStream) the encoded string directly and if necessary, replace the characters of a Generic Base64 string ('=', '+' and '/') with characters used in web-safe strings ('-' and '_').

The question is, how can I get a string from the 'CryptoStream' initialized with the 'ToBase64Transform' instance and then pass it to Base64WebSafe as usual with the 'ToBase64String()' method without affecting performance?

This is my code:

```
/** <summary> Encodes a File by using Base64 Encoding. </summary>
<param name = "inputPath" > The Path where the File to be Encoded is Located. </param>

<param name = "outputPath" > The Path where the Encoded File will be Saved. </param>
<param name = "isSecureBase" > A boolean that Determines if the Base64 string will be Generated as a Web-safe string or not. </param> */

internal static void EncodeFile(string inputPath, string outputPath, bool isSecureBase)
{
using FileStream inputFile = Archive_Manager.OpenAndReadFile(inputPath);
ToBase64Transform fileEncoder = new ToBase64Transform();

using CryptoStream outputFile = new CryptoStream(inputFile, fileEncoder, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
inputFile.CopyTo(outputFile);

if(isSecureBase == true)
{
// encodedString.TrimEnd(base64_trailingChar).Replace(base64_concatChar, url_concatChar).Replace(base64_strSeparator, url_strSeparator); 
}


}
```

Thanks in advance!

What I tryed: to get the bytes from the CryptoStream by using 'ToArray' but this just doubles the amount of RAM needed for storing the bytes and converting them to their string representation.

What I am expecting: a fast method where I can be able to generate Base64 Web-Safe string by using the CryptoStream class and the ToBase64Transform from System.Security.Criptography namespace.